# Get Soap last response

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

How to get last response from soap when it throws exception?

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $config);
$client->__soapCall($this->action, $payloadOutput, null, $headerOutput, $outputHeaders);
$client->__getLastResponse() // returns null
```

exceptions: false

when
exceptions: true
trace: true 
php throws exception but i need the received xml from soap

Comment: And what does the exception tells you?

Answer (score 1):

Set `trace` to `true` in your `$config` array.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Philio: `$client->__getLastResponse()` will return response if trace is set to true. If set to false, it returns null. This is the answer.

Comment: The question mentioned "trace: true", hence looked like not a valid answer.

Comment: @Philio: all he mentioned, that when `exceptions=true` it throws exception, which means that he has some error. After he solves his error, for getting last response, he needs `trace=true`.

Comment: Ah, ignore that then :)